# Root task object is not available in MS Project Tasks collection (VSTO)

Tags: vsto, ms-project

I am working with Visual Studio 2010 and targeting MS Project 2013 and for some reason when I iterate through the Tasks collection, the ultimate root does not show up.

For reference, I am using the built in template: "Commercial Construction"

## Here is a snippet of my code:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject;

Project project;
project = Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActiveProject;

foreach (Task t in project.Tasks)
{
    // Do something with the task
}
```

All the tasks EXCEPT the ultimate root shows up. The main problem with this is:

1) How do I create an ultimate root task through VSTO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out. The "ultimate root" is contained in a separate property:

```
Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask
```

Comment: Beyond that, it looks as though this is only going to happen when there "is" a Summary Task. In the case of the template, there is a Summary Task and hence this problem to begin with.